# Argument of type '(content: string, node: Element | null) => boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Matcher'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have a React Typescript app and while unit testing I used below code to find an element by its textContent:

```js
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";

export function getByTextContent(textMatch: string | RegExp): HTMLElement {
  return screen.getByText((content, node) => {
    const hasText = (node: Element) =>
      node.textContent === textMatch || node.textContent?.match(textMatch);
    const nodeHasText = hasText(node as Element);
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node?.children || []).every(
      (child) => !hasText(child)
    );
    return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText;
  });
}
```

I took the code from [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/410#issuecomment-797486513)

My tests passes, but the app crashes with the below error:

```js
Argument of type '(content: string, node: Element | null) => boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Matcher'.
  Type '(content: string, node: Element | null) => boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MatcherFunction'.
    Type 'boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.  TS2345

    2 | 
    3 | export function getByTextContent(textMatch: string | RegExp): HTMLElement {
  > 4 |   return screen.getByText((content, node) => {
      |                           ^
    5 |     const hasText = (node: Element) =>
    6 |       node.textContent === textMatch || node.textContent?.match(textMatch);
    7 |     const nodeHasText = hasText(node as Element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you're using `?` (as in `node.textContent?.match(textMatch);`) the result might be `undefined`, while it is fine for javascript, TS sees that `return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText;` can potentially be `return undefined && undefined` and points out that `undefined` is not quite `boolean`. One way out of it is `return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText || false;`